# How to view the source of an online .py file that displays HTML?

Tags: python, http, view, web

There's a site I visit and the URL bar says http://www.sitename.com/program.py?arg=value&otherArg=otherValue

How can I view the source code in the file program.py?

Comment: If any programming language were to allow you to figure out server side source code through webpage, I would be scared to use that. Unless the sourcecode is open sourced/freely available, unlike js/css you cannot access the source code of the .py file

Comment: If the source code included any sort of secrets like database access passwords this would be a security hole. Even letting you see exactly how they sanitize data submitted from users would give potential hackers a leg up if their sanitization wasn't bulletproof. This is something that is to be actively prevented - the guide to Django/mod_wsgi at https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/IntegrationWithDjango even points this out explicitly: **"Note that this directory should never be created under DocumentRoot of the Apache installation or any other directory exposed via Apache web server."**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, **you cannot.** The Python script isn't sent to your web browser, only the output from running it. You can see the HTML it generates along with any CSS and JavaScript files the HTML references, but you can't see the code that generated that HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Use FTP/FTPS/SFTP to access the website's directory structure.  In general, you can't do this unless you are the site owner or an authorized agent, with the appropriate access id and password.

This is true of any server-side technology (such as PHP, ASP/ASP.NET, Java, CGI, etc.)  You get to see HTML because it "executes" on the browser.  Server-side programs are executed on the server and the server code is never transmitted to clients during normal HTTP request processing.  So, you need another protocol that treats files as files and not programs to be run.